# Pasting via "p" not working in normal mode in Telescope

Tags: neovim, plugin, plugin-telescope

If I open Telescope for file or text search and switch to normal mode within the Telescope prompt and press `p`, nothing happens.

Does anyone know how I can enable pasting via `p` in normal mode in Telescope?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and think I found the source of the problem. If you copy something with new line characters, pasting it into the (single-line) Telescope search won't work. You can e.g. see if something contains a newline character by running `:reg` and check for trailing `^J` characters (at least on Arch Linux) in the relevant register.

To bypass this problem, make sure to only yank single-line content, e.g. with `0Y` instead of `yy`.